# How to hook into "register_rest_field" to modify the behavior of a custom field?

Tags: rest-api

Suppose that in one plugin (let's call it plugin A) I register a `country` custom field for requests that query users via the Wordpress REST API:

```
register_rest_field( "user", "country", [
   "get_callback" => array( $this, "get_country" ),
   "update_callback" => array( $this, "set_country" ),
   "schema" => [
      "type" => "string",
      "description" => "The user's country",
      "arg_options" => [
         "sanitize_callback" => function( $value ) {
            return sanitize_text_field( $value );
         },
         "validate_callback" => function( $value ) {
            return is_string( $value );
         }
      ]
   ]
]);
```

I've discovered I can make the field required by adding `"required" => true` to the `schema` array, but what if I only want to make the field required if a certain plugin (let's call it plugin B) is active?

I could check in plugin A if plugin B is active, but I'd rather use some hook in plugin B because it's cleaner and more future-proof. Is there any way to hook into `register_rest_field` and modify the behavior of a REST API field, or something else to the same effect?

Comment: Can you modify plugin A (that has the `register_rest_field()` command in it)?

Comment: @kero Yes I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most simple solution would be to use a custom filter for this. It could look something like:

```php
$schema = apply_filters('pluginA/register/country', [
    "type" => "string",
    "description" => "The user's country",
    "arg_options" => [
        "sanitize_callback" => function( $value ) {
            return sanitize_text_field( $value );
        },
        "validate_callback" => function( $value ) {
            return is_string( $value );
        },
    ]
]);
register_rest_field( "user", "country", [
    "get_callback" => array( $this, "get_country" ),
    "update_callback" => array( $this, "set_country" ),
    "schema" => $schema,
]);
```

Now in your other plugin, you simply add a filter and add the required flag or not:

```php
add_filter('pluginA/register/country', function(array $schema): array {
    $schema['required'] = true;
    return $schema;
});
```

Of course the name of the filter can be freely chosen, it probably makes sense to use some kind of vendor prefix, so it doesn't clash with filters defined by somebody else.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could use `apply_filters` so granularly, never thought about it... Pretty powerful actually. Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: You're welcome! Usually I avoid writing custom filters, but it seems that `register_rest_field` doesn't easily allow to change stuff without more digging. Additionally, I think (you need to test it) that you can use `'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'` instead of needing the anonymous function there.

Comment: Yeah I think that's by design, in the api docs they clearly say it's strongly discouraged to modify default fields, but it seems that as a result it becomes difficult to modify a custom field too. And you're right about using named functions: I've used it somewhere else and it works (both for 'sanitize_callback' and 'validate_callback')